# Resolve queries that are supersets of cached queries in Apollo Client

Tags: graphql, apollo, react-apollo, apollo-client

I use the apollo-cache-inmemory on my client and I try to work with cache.

Should I complement queries that are supersets of cached queries and to be more precise, how to make this manually?

For example, I have two queries: `booksConnection` and `author` and I want  `booksConnection` to benefit from `author` (

```
 query booksConnection(...) {
   booksConnection(...) {
     _id
     title 

     authors {
       _id
       name 
     }
   }
 }



 query author($_id: ID!) {
   author(_id: $_id) {
     _id
     name
   }
 }
```

I suppose that ApolloClient do it yourself, but is there a way to do it **manually**?